# JDBC runs fine when libraries extracted into runnable jar, but not when they are just packaged

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, jar

As the title says, when I export my program as a runnable jar with the referenced libraries extracted into the jar, I am able to run it just fine and JDBC is able to connect to the database. However, when I export it with the referenced libraries simply packaged, I get the error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306".

Additionally, the program works just fine in Eclipse when I run it. The problem only arises when I export it. Because of how this program is going to be implemented, I can't have the libraries extracted to the jar. They must be packaged alongside it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *"I can't have the libraries extracted to the jar. They must be packaged alongside it."*. By "alongside it" do you mean "outside of the runnable jar containing the classes for the code that I have written"? If so, that's the "copy" option in the Eclipse export (to runnable jar) dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Don't unpack third-party libraries into your JAR. It defeats the whole purpose of JARs, which is to package libraries independently of each other. It's a really, really bad idea.

What *exactly* do you mean by "export it with the referenced libraries simply packaged"? Please lay out the *exact* steps that involves so we can answer your question. You almost certainly didn't do the right thing when you "packaged" your application. Since we don't know what you did wrong, we cannot help.

Normally you place library JARs in the same directory or a controlled subdirectory of the directory in which you place your application JAR. You specify them in the classpath using your application JAR's manifest. READ THE JAR DOCUMENTATION for how to do all that.

You can package your JAR and all dependent JARs together using an installer, or simply by putting them together into a ZIP (or JAR) file that you extract into a deployment directory. Not in the outermost ZIP, but in your actual application JAR is where where you put your manifest with classpath.

The deployed directory structure will be something like this:

```
application_directory/
  |
  |-- yourApplication.jar
  |
  |-- lib/
        |-- thirdParty.jar
        |-- anotherThirdParty.jar
        |-- someOther.jar
        |-- ...
```

Do read up on JAR files and their manifest structure in the Oracle documentation.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html